# Turn on/off Debian screen / HDMI

Tags: debian, x11, xrandr, xset

I want to turn off / on the screen remotely via SSH / using cron. I'm using Debian 9. I've found some commands, but they're not working at all.

I got commands from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62858/turn-off-monitor-using-command-line) answer.

**These commands are working (vbetool), but when I turn on the screen back, it glitches (something similar to [this](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7SeY1HrfPKM/maxresdefault.jpg)).**

```
sudo vbetool dpms off
sudo vbetool dpms on
```

**Using xset I'm not able to turn the screen on after a few seconds.**

```
xset -display :0.0 dpms force off 
xset -display :0.0 dpms force on
```

**Using xrandr I can't control the screen from SSH.**

```
xrandr --output CRT1 --off
xrandr --output CRT1 --auto
```

Comment: Related questions are of course https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33167/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68458/5132 .

Comment: @JdeBP That only answers the last case, and It's not that efficient...

Comment: _related_ is not synonymous with _duplicate_.